# Is it possible to take Cleric & Cloistered Cleric on the same character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

My archer cleric(7x Normal Cleric) would like to take a level of Cloistered Cleric for access to a third domain. Is this possible, or should I be looking elsewhere for more domain choices?

TL;DR Are standard Cleric + Cloistered Cleric levels mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Whether a character can advance in a base class *and* advance separately in a variant of that base class is determined by the DM

The section on [Multiclassing And Variant Classes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm) says that

> Multiclassing between variants of the same class is a tricky subject. In cases where a single class offers a variety of paths (such as the totem barbarian or the monk fighting styles), **the easiest solution is simply to bar multiclassing between different versions of the same class (just as a character can't multiclass between different versions of specialist wizards)**. For variants that are wholly separate from the character class—such as the bardic sage or the urban ranger—multiclassing, even into multiple variants of the same class, is probably okay. Identical class features should stack if gained from multiple versions of the same class (except for spellcasting, which is always separate).

In other words, the game doesn't say *No*, but it does offer the DM the option to say *No* and not feel bad. The general Internet assumption seems to be that such a thing just isn't done and that the DM *will* say no. Your DM may vary.

Personally, I've never had a DM explicitly *allow*, for example, a Cleric 1 / Cloistered Cleric 1 character, nor have I ever DMed a campaign wherein a player asked if that were an option. Were I DMing a low-level or short-term campaign I probably *wouldn't* allow such multiclassing. Losing the spell level hurts, but the 3 domains and the volume of low-level spells more than makes up for that loss. In a high-level campaign I probably *would* allow such multiclassing, as everyone already possesses a host of resources and the reduced high-level spell availability *really* matters.

Comment: This clears things up a little. Interesting that the spell level **wouldn't** stack with standard cleric.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Can you back up that last claim in your comment, re: Turn Undead? That does not match my understanding: the rule you yourself quote in the answer say that the same class features gained from taking different variants of the same class stack.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Still, the general principle you were citing, where is that found? I’ve been in discussions before that hinged on that point, and I don’t think anyone could produce satisfactory rules-quotes.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Uh... I cannot remember any such conversation; I don’t really have a stance. My understanding matched yours, but the last time I discussed it with someone who disagreed, I found myself unable to back it up and was thus curious. But we have strayed far from the topic of this answer.

Comment: Could "re-training" be a thing?

Answer (score 2):

#### There are two issues

First, as [described by Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/62966/4563), the DM may allow you to multiclass between variants of a class.

Second, even if cleric and cloistered cleric are considered the same class, there is evidence in the rules that you can multiclass between the cleric class of two different deities. Specifically, from *Player’s Handbook II*,

> What if a cleric of Hextor finds new meaning and purpose in serving Heironeous after a dramatic conversion experience? Such a character **need not** become a multiclass ex-cleric of Hextor/cleric of Heironeous.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

That you “need not” implies that you *could*, if you wanted. The tricky part is maintaining sufficient devotion to both deities to continue having your power in both: to be an Ex-Cleric of X/Cloistered Cleric of Y definitely seems plausible, but ex-cleric does nothing for you. Whether one can be a cleric of a second faith without becoming an ex-cleric in the first is entirely the DM’s call, and one imagines that in the overwhelming majority of cases, the answer would be no. Still, a DM might allow a Cloistered Cleric of [Pantheon that includes X]/Cleric of X to work.

As for whether or not this is a good idea, domains are very fun and useful; making a character based around domains rather than spells would be interesting. I would probably allow it, for the right character. As powerful as domains are, spells are much more so. At 2nd level, specifically, such a character might have a fairly large advantage over a regular cleric, which could be a problem. But beyond that point, I feel most clerics would rather have their next level of spells a level sooner, than get two more domains.

Comment: Can you envision a scenario wherein a character *would* pick to become, for example, a Cleric 1 of Heironeous/ex-Cleric 17 of Hextor? For a dude with a really high Wisdom, that choice seems decidedly unwise.

Comment: The character in question wouldn't be a cleric of two gods, just taking a level in Cloistered to get the third domain of the god they already worship. The theoretical loss of a spell level hurts, however.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I did say that it does nothing for you. No, I can think of no reason that this is desirable, just that it’s apparently possible.

Comment: O, I know. I was just curious if you knew of such a scenario. (Mainly because I couldn't think of one.)

Comment: @Rook If you are only looking for a *third* domain (as opposed to a third, fourth, and fifth), the contemplative prestige class from *Complete Divine* may be more useful to you than cloistered cleric anyway, since that progresses spellcasting. It’s fairly high-level though.